# How to increase max heap size in tomcat ? There is no catalina.bat file in my tomcat/bin directory

Tags: tomcat

I want to increase heap size in tomcat. But there is no  catalina.bat file in my tomcat/bin directory. I have 2 jar file and tomcat.exe and tomcatw.exe. file
help me

Answer (score 1):

Run `tomcatw.exe` from the command line; you should see a "Java" tab. Click that and there should be an option for max memory size.